# PHP array in WHILE

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I have this piece of code:

```
<?php
$counter = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($bim_coupons_price)){?>
    <div class="clone">
        <div id="start_date_countdown">
            <span>No</span>
            <input id="start_datetimepicker<?php echo $counter?>" type="text" name="start_date_countdown[]" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['start_date_countdown'][0])){echo $_POST['start_date_countdown'][0];}else{echo $row['start_date_countdown'];}?>"/>
        </div>  
        <div id="end_date_countdown">
            <span>Līdz</span>
            <input id="end_datetimepicker<?php echo $counter?>" type="text" name="end_date_countdown[]" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['end_date_countdown'][0])){echo $_POST['end_date_countdown'][0];}else{echo $row['end_date_countdown'];}?>"/>
        </div>
        <div id="price_container">
            <span>Cena</span>
            <input type="text" id="price_new" name="price_new[]" value="<?php echo $row['price_new']?>"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
<?php $counter++; } ?>
```

Problem is there that this while loop will executes 3 times and I need to change `$_POST['start_date_countdown'][0])` every time to `$_POST['start_date_countdown'][1])`, `$_POST['start_date_countdown'][2])` etc...

How I can do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change `$_POST['INDEX_KEY'][0]` to `$_POST['INDEX_KEY'][$counter]`. `INDEX_KEY` pertains to `start_date_countdown` and `end_date_countdown`

Comment: why need change end_date_countdown i think it will start_date_countdown?

Comment: @RakeshSharma forgot to mention, that I need change both of them.

Comment: @Cristian Thank you a lot! I have spent so many time for that, but solution was so easy...

Answer (score 0):

Well u are already are using variable $counter.You can make it $_POST['start_date_countdown'][$counter]